# Vagrant box downloaded without extension

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I tried adding a vagrant box for Windows Server 2012 using the following command -
**vagrant box add promet/windows2012**

This was taking quite a lot of time ( The size is 10.3 GB). This can be seen below-

[image]

So to cut short the waiting period , I picked up the downloadable link (https://vagrantcloud.com/promet/boxes/windows2012/versions/1.1/providers/virtualbox.box) from above and downloaded it manually via Download Manager. (See pic below, the .box url have been redirected )

[image]

The Problem is that the downloaded file does not have a .box extension.
So how do I now do a **vagrant box add** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just fine - As long as the checksum matches, you can rename your downloaded file with a `.box` extension (like `virtualbox.box` originally) and you will add the box using the following command

```
vagrant box add --name promet/windows2012 <path of the downloaded box file>
```